# bootstrap remove vertical gap between cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We are using bootstrap for developing a new site and we ran into a problem.

The basic html code :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8" style="height: 200px;">
    Yellow
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="height: 400px;">
    Red
</div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="height: 200px;">
    Blue
</div>
```

what we want is for the yellow and blue div to be on the left (no gap between them) and have the red div on the right. But on a mobile we want the order to be yellow, red, blue.

The xs/sm version of the site is ok, but if you look at lg or md you get a big gap between the yellow and blue div's. Is there a way to remove that gap?

Comment: Martijn, is it ok if i will use media queries or Min-height? as i have solution but asking for these condition..so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for appears to be coming in future releases ([open request here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13690)), but for now you'll have to [add some css](https://github.com/Natshah/bootstrap-pull) to add conditional classes by media query.

http://jsbin.com/cefilatudi/1/edit?html,css,output

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  /** Pull right **/
  .pull-right-md {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry this code is not working as still there is big gap if you will look more then 999px and i don't think we should use custom media query that's why i asked op as i have solution with media but waiting for the reply..

Comment: Why not use media query? That's what bootstrap does already. And it's working fine on the jsbin example I sent. Do you mean it doesn't work on your site? Because then you may have some other code interfering.

Comment: m not the op but another developer who wanted to help and ok if we will use custom bootstrap then if op will upgrade the bootstrap then he will face this issue so we should ask op for this and second thing, check site in above then 1000px then you will see there is big gap..dnt check in jsbin but try to create normal html page then you will see..

Comment: wow..seems on SO now people are marking qus as answer even its wrong..great..go on then..time to leave SO

Comment: Can  you explain how it's wrong Leo? Works for me everywhere I try it. I'm not making any changes to bootstrap classes, but adding a new class. Future bootstrap versions shouldn't break it. If anything, judging by the feature request I shared, this very class may be added to bootstrap anyway.

Comment: try to give background color to all div then  you will see..i have screenshot but don't want to post in answer..just change your jsbin and put bg color then you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Small example using some colors:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKLMY?editors=110

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-4 {
    float: right;
  }
}
```